# How to use razor engine for email templating with image src

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've found this [link](http://blog.falafel.com/smarter-email-templates-in-asp-net-with-razorengine/) on how to using Razor Engine for email templates in asp.net and it worked great. But I've tried to have a logo in the email template with an image.

Something like this:

`EmailTemplate.cshtml` (this by the way is a strongly-type view)

```
<html>
<body>
  <img src="logo.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

and when I try to submit it on email, it seems that the image path was not read, it only rendered an X in the content.

I'm thinking to pass the image path as part of the Model but it seems odd that way. Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The email is rendered *within the context of the email application*, not your website. As a result, a request for "logo.jpg" doesn't mean anything, as there's no local place to pull that from within the email application. That's why you either need an absolute URL so it knows to pull from your domain, or you need to embed the image in the email.

Comment: I opt to using the absolute path since its much simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To see image everywhere you can use these options:

**Absolute Url**

You can simply use full absolute path of image for example    `"http://example.com/images/logo.png"`

IMO It is the most simple option and recommended for your problem.

**Attachment**

As mentioned by Mason in comments You can attach image to mail and then put image tag and use[`ContentId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.contentid?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=exchange-ews-api) of attachment:

```
//(Thanks to Mason for comment and Thanks to  Bartosz Kosarzyck for sample code)
string subject = "Subject";
string body = @"<img src=""$CONTENTID$""/> <br/> Some Content";

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("from@example.com");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@example.com"));
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

string contentID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
body = body.Replace("$CONTENTID$", "cid:" + contentID);

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
//path of image or stream
LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Users\R.Aghaei\Desktop\outlook.png", "image/png");
imagelink.ContentId = contentID;
imagelink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "mail.example.com";
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@example.com", "password");
client.Send(mail);
```

**Data Uri**

you can use data uri (data:image/png;base64,....).

*Not Recommended* because of weak support in most of mail clients, I tested it with `Outlook.com(web)` and `OutlookWebAccess(web)` and `Office Outlook(Windows)` and `Outlook(windows 8.1)` and unfortunately it worked only on `OutlookWebAccess(web)`.

Comment: Assuming email clients support data URI's....do you have any experience with that? I wouldn't just assume they support it.

Comment: Also, there'd a third option. Grabbing the image, attaching it to the email, and using a content ID to get it into the email body.

Comment: @mason Thank you for your comment. I tested it with outlook.com(web) and outlookwebaccess (web) and office outlook (windows) and outlook (windows 8.1) and unfortunately it worked only on outlookwebaccess. and it seems there is no good support to use data uri.

Comment: @mason I edited the answer and made data url not recommended, also added an example of using Attachment.ContentId and mentioned your comment in answer. Thank you. Hope you find the answer useful:)

Answer (score 0):

The GraphAPI has changed since the last answer was accepted. It may have changed again by the time you read this. Godspeed.

You said you're using Razor and the accepted solution includes some find\replace, which is what Razor does. So let's start there.

Inside your `EmailTemplate.cshtml` you can call out the logo path using Razor syntax:

```
<img src="@Model.MainLogo" />
```

That gets set in the data model when you're building the template:

```
string contentIDlogo = "logo.png";
string templateName = "EmailTemplate.cshtml";

object dataModel = new
{
    MainLogo = $"cid:{contentIDlogo}"
};

// This is where you render the Razor to HTML body string.
string emailTemplate = _razorTemplateCache.RenderBasicTemplate(templateName, dataModel);

// Define a simple e-mail message.
var mailMessage = new Message
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = emailTemplate
    },
    ToRecipients = toRecipients.ToList()
};

// Add the image as an attachment to the email.
mailMessage.HasAttachments = true;
byte[] logoBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(contentIDlogo);
mailMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
{
    new FileAttachment
    {
        ContentBytes = logoBytes,
        ContentType = "image/png",
        Name = contentIDlogo,
        IsInline = true,
        ContentId = contentIDlogo,
        Size = logoBytes.Length
    }
};
```

Now that you have a message you can post it using the Graph API.
My example is using `Microsoft.Graph (5.9.0)`

```
// Define our new Microsoft Graph client. 
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_credentials, _scopes, Endpoint);

var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = theEmail,
    SaveToSentItems = true
};

// Send mail as the given user. 
var fromUser = graphServiceClient.Users[_sendAsUserObjectId];
await fromUser.SendMail.PostAsync(mailMessage, null, cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```