# Creating an Email Template vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, templates

I am doing a MassMailing service so i do campaigns and things like that for companies...

I already have the core of the MassMailing which is sending/retrieving email data from SendGrid(the smtp service i use)

My problem now is creating a user interface to create an actual email message template on a `<input>` that a user can interact with the input by adding images and formatted text and such... What i want to receive from the text the user makes is the HTML so i can send it directly to my Database to send it to MassMailing service.

What i want to do is something like this:
[image: Email template]

But what returns from the input is just HTML...

I don't know if i was very specific with the post if i wasen't i'm sorry and i will try to explain it other way...

Comment: You can use an html editor which store `img` tags using absolute url. THen the user should upload the image in your site and then insert the image in to the html editor. Also you can use a place holder instead of images and map images and place holders and then use content id to attach images to the messages. Take a look at [How to use razor engine for email templating with image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767314/how-to-use-razor-engine-for-email-templating-with-image-src)

Comment: @RezaAghaei What i want is them to build an Email not attach images... It's like making a flyer but in digital format so when a customer opens the Email sees the full content of that Email like a flyer...

Comment: The options which is described in linked post is the only solutions to have images in emails. Also that kind of attachment (using contentid) shows image in body of email.

Comment: @RezaAghaei what i was asking for was something like this https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: I know, and when I say *html editor* I mean something like TinyMCE, FCKEditor, MarkDown and so on. Using any of those editors doesn't change my answer.

Comment: I guess you couldn't understand what I mean. Probably you will return to above comments and the linked post in the near future and will find it useful :)