# HTML Email Body Base64 Image not showing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send an email on my application (asp.net C#)I tried every answer on SO to display base64 image on the email body. but nothing workout so far. if anyone helps me to solve this problem that will be great.
This is HTML Code

```
<tr style="min-height:60px;margin-top:50px;width:100%;padding: 0px;color: black;clear: left;text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom:40px;">
           <td style="margin-top:100px;height:60px; background-position-x: center;background-position-y: center;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
               <img src="##FooterImage" style="margin-left: 73%;" />
           </td>
       </tr>

    emailBodyLoaded = emailBodyLoaded.Replace("##FooterImage", "'cid:" + iconResource.ContentId + @"'");
    byte[] iconBytes = new BLL.Core.Domain.items(new ageContext()).GetitemsLogo(inspData.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString());
    System.IO.MemoryStream iconBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(iconBytes);
    LinkedResource iconResource = new LinkedResource(iconBitmap, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    iconResource.ContentId = "Icon";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32767496/3110834

Comment: Base64 does not work in most email clients. Use normal images.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using a normal image

Comment: Check the linked post. It's a complete working example.

Answer (score 2):

first you should check if your base64 string is valid.you can do that using any of the online tools like [base64-image](https://www.base64-image.de/) .how ever please refer to this [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/chayed/hq18az93/2/) fiddle which displays a base64 image using html `img` control.

EDIT: please check in your 'IMG' src have `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before the base64 string.this where it determines the image format.if this doen't work please try replacing 'jpeg' with 'png' eg:- `data:image/png;base64,`

Comment: please refer to the "Edit" in my Answer